# How to get value of environment variable from passed command line parameter

Tags: windows, scripting, batch

I have to use/reference an environment variable value which will be passed as a command line argument.  Something like below

```
set myvar=%1
echo Value of %myvar% is %%myvar%%
```

Here in `%%myvar%%` I want to reference the value of that environment varible

A typical call to this script will be

```
script.bat JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: Since it's environment variable, why it must be passed as a command line parameter in the first place? Why can't the script use environment variables directly?

Comment: @EsaJokinen I need to create some scripts which will test whether certain environment variables exists before I start some tasks.  Like before working with Java I want a script to check whether JAVA_HOME, ANT_HOME, M2_HOME is already set.  In another language I may need some other environmental variables checked.  I want to create a utility script which will check any given variable and to use that utility in other scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the intermediate `myvar` variable. If you want it, then simply substitute `%myvar%` for `%1` below.

You need two rounds of expansion.

**Option 1 - CALL**

```
@echo off
call echo %%%1%%
```

In the first parsing phase

- `%%` expands to `%`
- `%1` expands to `JAVA_HOME`
- `%%` expands to `%`

In the CALL phase, `%JAVA_HOME%` expands to the value you are looking for.

**Option 2 - Delayed Expansion**

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo !%1!
```

The delayed expansion form is much easier to read

---

See [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/1012053) for more info